# OWA_COOKIE won't delete

Tags: sql, oracle, cookies, plsql

I have a function to remove a cookie from my browser, and for some strange reason it all my details are correct, Its being done and monitored using firebug in Mozilla, below is my create, delete and read cookie functions:

```
    PROCEDURE create_Session_Cookie (i_Value IN VARCHAR2)
   IS
   BEGIN
      -- Create a cookie
      OWA_COOKIE.send (name      => 'CreateCookie',
                       VALUE     => i_Value,
                       expires   => SYSDATE + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE,
                       PATH      => '/hello');
   --owa_util.http_header_close;

   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         NULL;
   END create_Session_Cookie;

 PROCEDURE delete_Session_Cookie
 IS 
 BEGIN
 OWA_COOKIE.REMOVE(
                   name   => 'CreateCookie',
                   val    => read_Session_Cookie
                  );
 END delete_Session_Cookie;


   FUNCTION read_Session_Cookie
      RETURN VARCHAR2
   IS
      l_SessionCookie   OWA_COOKIE.COOKIE;
      l_SessionValue    VARCHAR2 (50);
   BEGIN
      -- Read cookie into cookie record
      l_SessionCookie := OWA_COOKIE.GET ('CreateCookie');
      -- Extract value from cookie record
      l_SessionValue := l_SessionCookie.VALS (1);

      RETURN l_SessionValue;
   -- If the cookie does not exist an exception will be thrown
   -- so we return null
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         RETURN NULL;
   END read_Session_Cookie;`
```

Any one have an issue like this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed.  I have had VERY mixed results with OWA_COOKIE when it comes to removing them.  The solution I just implemented is working in my sandbox.

Rather than using the OWA_COOKIE.REMOVE call, I just perform another set, but set the expiration date to some date in the past.

After watching the cookies being set using fiddler2, it looks like this is all that should be going on anyway.  The difference is the path and secure options get set and my cookies are actually going away.  Hope this helps.

```
OWA_COOKIE.SEND(
           NAME => 'CreateCookie',
           VALUE => read_session_cookie, --Could also set this to null
           EXPIRES => SYSDATE -1,
           PATH => '/',
           DOMAIN => 'mydomain.com', 
           SECURE => NULL);
```